# How to turn JSON into URL links and then get data when clicked on

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, express

I have some JSON data.

I am looping through it and placing some of the values into an HTML link element like:

```
 getPatchList: function() {
             $.ajax({
                 url: "/returneddata"
             }).done(function(returnedJSON) {



                 for (i = 0; i < returnedJSON.docs.length; i += 1)
                     $("#application-area").append("<a href=/patch" + "/" + returnedJSON.docs[i].patchName + "/" +
                         returnedJSON.docs[i]._id + ">" + returnedJSON.docs[i].patchName + "</a>");


             });
         },
```

**The problem is** *I want to grab all the JSON data associated with the respective url link when the user clicks on it and use that as a query to find the corresponding MongoDB object, then grab it and play with the data.* If you notice the url contains the mongoDB _id of the document. Thus when they click on a link the url returned is something like:

```
http://localhost:3000/patch/name_of_patch/535bd6e89ee893c000c5858c
```

To solve this I am thinking that it would be possible to set up a route in express that concatenates an object that contains the rest of the url but I am not sure how to even get this information from my url link back to my node app. It would look looks something like:

```
   app.get('/patch' + '/' + patchName +'/' + restOfURID, function(req, res) {

           // find mongBD document with resOfURLID and do something with it
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is probably the param function in express

`app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res){
   // id will now be accessible through req.params
   res.send('user ' + req.params.id);
 });`

however, I am not sure why you need that. Can't you put the data into your url as GET query parameters? the URL can have the following form

`http://localhost:3000/patch?patchName=name_of_patch&mongoID=535bd6e89ee8...`

and now you will be able to access these variables in req.query

`app.get('/patch', function(req, res) {
   res.send('patch name ' + req.query.patchName + ', id ' + req.query.mongoID);
 });`